# Interfaces injection implementation coding design pattern

Tags: oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection, interface

I am using interface dependency injection but thinking about how I can make it scalable if one interface has any change. For example:

```
function updateStatistics(Interface myInterface)
{ 
    myInterface->prepareStatistics;
    myInterface->syncStatistics;
    myInterface->doSomething;
    myInterface->doSomething2;
    ...
}
```

Assume that only one of the implementations of the interface needs to have an additional feature such as an intermediate function like

```
 function updateStatistics(Interface myInterface)
 { 
     myInterface->prepareStatistics;
     // Do function for only certain implementations
     myInterface->syncStatistics;
    myInterface->doSomething;
    myInterface->doSomething2;
    ...
 }
```

What is the right way to go on about this? I have come across many solutions

1. Create and call a new abstract method in the interface but leave the body empty where its not needed. However, this breaks the concept of abstraction in OOP because if I have 10 implementations, a new engineer won't know that the body of the method is left empty in some places.
2. Create another interface and those that need it should implement it. I can check if the injected interface contains the extra interfaces and then call those functions. This is my favourite solution yet but it can bloat my function with if statements.

```
    function updateStatistics(Interface myInterface)
    { 
        myInterface->prepareStatistics;

        if (myInterface instanceof extensionInterface) {
            // Do function for only certain implementations
        }
        myInterface->syncStatistics;
        ...
    }
```

3. Breaking the `updateStatistics` function into its own interface method. But the main parts of this code will majorly be repeated and I would prefer one source of truth.

I want to know what the correct OOP way is to go on about this and not a hacky solution.

Answer (score 2):

> Assume that only one of the interfaces needs to implement an intermediate function like

Why would that be? An interface never *needs* to implement anything. *Interfaces* don't implement behaviour; *classes* do, by implementing interfaces.

This may strike you as semantic nitpicking, but I highlight it because this is one of several phrases in the OP that seem to imply that the interfaces are driven by implementation details.

If, however, interfaces only mirror the implementation details of their implementing classes, then why even have the interfaces? This would, indeed, entail that when you change the implementation, you may need to change the interface, and thereby breaking client code.

Instead, the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) suggests the opposite:

> Abstractions should not depend upon details. Details should depend upon abstractions.
>
> - Robert C. Martin, [Agile Principles, Patterns, and Practices in C#](https://blog.ploeh.dk/ref/appp), ch. 11

Instead of extracting interface definitions from implementation details, reverse the ownership of the design so that

> clients [...] own the abstract interfaces
>
> - Robert C. Martin, [Agile Principles, Patterns, and Practices in C#](https://blog.ploeh.dk/ref/appp), ch. 11

Figure out what client code *needs*, and design the interface around those needs.

> I can check if the injected interface contains the extra interfaces and then call those functions. This is my favourite solution yet but it can bloat my function with if statements.

If you perform run-time type tests, you've broken polymorphism, which is the whole point of interfaces. It may lead to [Shotgun Surgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun_surgery), because you have to repeat the same flow control structure in every place that consumes the interface in question. [Refactoring](https://blog.ploeh.dk/ref/refactoring) considers this a code smell.

Unfortunately, I can't tell you what to do instead, because the whole point of such a [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) exercise is to start with what client code needs, and the OP doesn't describe that.